# My Random Sudoku Generator Keeps Stalling

Tags: java, sudoku

For a programming course of mine, I have decided to create a Sudoku board in GUI. I've created a class for just the code of the board, and whenever the slot that needs to be filled can't be filled with anything, the board stalls, and I can't seem to make it restart. Any help? What is causing it to stall? How do I make it restart?

My code so far:

```
public class GameCode{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        //Declare array for the game's code
        int [][] slot = new int[9][9];
        int [] slotSectorNums = new int[9];
        int num = 1;
        int tries = 0;
        boolean taken = false;
        boolean complete = true;

        do{
            //Reset slot array
            for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++){
                for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++){

                    //Clear the slot
                    slot[x][y] = 0;
                }//End of y for loop
            }//End of x for loop

            //Loop through rows of the array
            for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++){

                //Loop through columns of the array
                for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++){
                    tries = 0;

                    do{
                        tries++;

                        //Make the check-variable true
                        taken = false;

                        //Generate random integer for num
                        num = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);

                        //Loop check within the row
                        for (int rowSlot = 0; rowSlot < 9; rowSlot++){

                            //Compare random number against row number
                            if (num == slot[rowSlot][column])
                                taken = true;
                        }//End of rowSlot loop

                        //Loop check within the column
                        for (int columnSlot = 0; columnSlot < 9; columnSlot++){

                            //Compare random number against column number
                            if(num == slot[row][columnSlot])
                                taken = true;
                        }
                    }while(taken == true && allTaken(row, column, slot) == false);
                    slot[row][column] = num;
                    temp(slot);
                }//End of column for loop
            }//End of row for loop
            temp(slot);
        }while(slot[8][8] != 0);
    }//End of main method

    public static int[] slotSectorNumDecide(int row, int column, int [][] slot){
        int [] slotNums = new int[9];
        int slotSectorRow = slotSectorRow(row) * 3;
        int slotSectorColumn = slotSectorColumn(column) * 3;
        int z = 0;

        //Loop for every slot
        for (int x = slotSectorRow; x < slotSectorRow + 2; x++){
            //Loop for every dimension
            for (int y = slotSectorColumn; y < slotSectorColumn + 2; y++){

                //Add the slot in the correct dimension to slotNums
                slotNums[z] = slot[x][y];

                //Increment the space in slotNums
                z++; 
            }//End of y for loop
        }//End of x for loop

        return slotNums;
    }//End of slot sectorSectorNumDecide

    public static int slotSectorRow(int row){
        int slotRow;
        slotRow = row / 3;
        System.out.println(row + " " + slotRow);

        return slotRow;
    }//End of slotSectorRow

    public static int slotSectorColumn(int column){
        int slotColumn;
        slotColumn = column / 3;
        System.out.println(column + " " + slotColumn);

        return slotColumn;
    }//End of slotSectorColumn method

    public static boolean allTaken(int row, int column, int [][] slot){
        int x = 1;

        for (int y = 0; y < 9 && x < 10; y++){
            for (int z = 0; z < 9 && x < 10; z++){
                if(slot[y][z] == x && x < 10)
                    x++;
            }//End of z for loop
        }//End of y for loop

        if (x == 10)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }//End of allTaken method

    public static void temp(int [][] slot){
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++){
                System.out.print("|" + slot[x][y]);
            }//End of y for loop
            System.out.println();
        }//End of x for loop
        System.out.println();
    }//End of temp method
}//End of class
```

Comment: What do you mean by stalling?  Do you mean it fails to find a solution? BTW: Using `Random.nextInt(9)` is likely to be much faster.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger and/or use logging to determine where the stall is occurring?

Comment: By stalling, I mean no output occurs, and it fails to find a solution (due to all available numbers being taken).
Debug says nothing.

Comment: This game is best solved with a backtracking algorithm, despite years ago I read its creator making naive claims about not being solved by computers. I can tell you the algorithm is efficient enough to run on constrained J2ME devices. It allows for both generation and solving.

Answer (score 1):

Your allTaken method doesn't seem to be doing what it should be.

My understanding is that you traverse the whole slot matrix and try to find one occurence of each number from 1 to 9:

```
    for(int y = 0; y < 9 && x < 10; y++) {
        for(int z = 0; z < 9 && x < 10; z++) {
            if(slot[y][z] == x && x < 10)
                x++;
        }// End of z for loop
    }// End of y for loop
```

But this won't work because you don't restart the search from the start once you've found a number. For example assume that the matrix has a 1 only at position [8][8], then the loops won't find 2, 3 or other numbers anywhere because the loops for y and z are finished.

One possible fix would be to keep track of all the unique numbers you have encountered in the matrix (you can store them in a set), and stop whenever the set has size 10.

But even with this fix I'm not sure your algorithm will work: from what I understood of your code, the allTaken function should verify whether all of the numbers occur not in the full matrix, but in a given row, or column (or 3 by 3 square).

In pseudocode this would be something like:

```
boolean allTaken(int row, int column, int[][] slot) {
  Set<Integer> taken = Collections.emptySet();

  // Add elements from the row
  for(int x=0; x<9; x++) {
    taken.add(slot[row][x]);
  }

  // Add elements from the column
  for(int y=0; y<9; y++) {
    taken.add(slot[y][column]);
  }

  // Check the 3-by-3 square this row/column is in

  // sx and sy are the top-left coordinates of this square
  int sx = (row/3)*3; 
  int sy = (column/3)*3;
  for(int dx=0; dx<3; dx++) {
    for(int dy=0; dy<3; dy++) {
        taken.add(slot[sx+dx][sy+dy]);
    }
  }

  // All options are taken if the numbers from 1 to 9 appear in the set
  // Zero will be present too because slot[row][col] is zero.
  // So we expect 10 elements.
  return taken.size() == 10;
}
```

Even with this you shouldn't expect the algorithm to be efficient: filling sudoku randomly won't work most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is once you reach a cell where no number fits because it is already somewhere in the cells column or row `taken`is always true and you loop indefinitely.

I also don't see why you would use random at all, this way you are wasting computation time by checking the same numbers over and over.

You better work with a list of numbers you did not yet test for a cell and which are not yet used somewhere on the way.

Also it seems your allTaken method is way off.

You probably want something like this:

```
public static boolean allTaken(int row, int column, int [][] slot){
    int z = 0;
    boolean[] taken = new boolean[10];

    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
      taken[slot[row][x]] = true;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
      taken[slot[x][column]] = true;
    }

    boolean f = true;
    for (boolean b : taken)
      f = f && b;

    return f;
}
```

Go from here and see how far you get.

Comment: Now with the code I have so far, it works great. The only thing I need to figure out now it how to get it to match up with slotSector. Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: I'd say I leave this up to you, for practice. Anyhow, basically instead of scanning just the cell row and colum, scan the sector too using the same `taken` array.